# Windows 10 change display scaling via hotkey

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

Is there a way to change the display scaling of a particular monitor to a predefined value via a hotkey?

I recently aquired a steam controller which lets me use my PC from a distance rather than having to be sat at the desk. It would be nice if I could trigger a hotkey to increase the scale of text and items on my big screen so it is easier to read and use at that distance. Is there any way of doing this?

I want to achieve the same effect as this slider and not change the actual resolution of the monitor:
[image: The setting I'm talking about]

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I couldn't find shortcut key because there is no such thing

however, since I need to develop stuff that should be supported in multiple resolutions I've found the quickest way to do that.

1. First, you need to extract the scales registry, run `regedit` and goto `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\PerMonitorSettings`
   do that when the scales setting are set to 100%, let's save the 100% settings into a file named `to100.reg`

since there are different registry key per machine you have to export the registry for the machine you work on - I can't give you my files because it will not work.

2. Do that for all relevant scales - I've stored the 100%, 125%, 150%, 175% (on my windows 10 the DpiValue is 0 for 100%, 1 for 125% etc...)
3. create this batch (logoutToResolution.bat) file in the same folder of the .reg files:

> ```
> @echo off
> CHOICE /C ABCD /N /T 10 /D A /M "Log out to resolution: A:100%%, B:125%%, C:150%%, D:175%%"
> IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET RESOLUTION_FILE=to100.reg
> IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET RESOLUTION_FILE=to125.reg
> IF ERRORLEVEL 3 SET RESOLUTION_FILE=to150.reg
> IF ERRORLEVEL 4 SET RESOLUTION_FILE=to175.reg
> REGEDIT.EXE  /S  "%~dp0%RESOLUTION_FILE%"
> shutdown -l
> ```

4. Now, when running this batch file you need to choose A for 100%, B for 125% etc... after choosing the registry will get updated and windows will log out automatically.
5. you can create a different batch for every reg file if you want.

the logout is a must because if you don't log out the UI will be drawn differently than it should.

Comment: Isn't this easier?:
https://superuser.com/questions/1334781/is-it-possible-to-change-display-scaling-via-command-line

Comment: Thanks for the link @AndyFielding, IMHO it's the same dirt with a different flavor. Both solutions are workarounds for some users your link will be more convenient and for some mine.