# Is it possible to change display scaling via command line?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, dpi, scaling

I've got a laptop with a 2560 x 1440 display, connected to 2 external 1080p monitors. The scaling is fine normally, with the native monitor at 125% and the 1080p monitors at 100%, but when I undock the laptop, sometimes the laptop goes to 200% scaling factor and I need to reset it manually in display settings.

I would like to find a command that emulates the setting here, such that I don't need to right click on the desktop and open display settings every time I unplug my external monitors:

[image]

The only registry keys/PowerShell commands I've found for this require logging out to take effect, which doesn't seem necessary given the GUI setting can take effect immediately.

Comment: You can have a look at this answer too:
https://superuser.com/a/1407846/195091

Comment: See also [my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1792335/177522) that tells you how to do this automatically upon connect/disconnect of an external monitor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below is a batch script that will emulate the keyboard strokes to manipulate the GUI to adjust the **Scale and layout** options and **Change the size or text, apps, and other items** when it runs. This uses `ms-settings:display` to open the **Display** screen, and then it presses the *tab key once* and the *up arrow 5 times* using [sendkeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html) to adjust the scale accordingly. It will press *Alt+F4* at the end keys to close the screen once it completes. This method builds a dynamic vb script with a batch script and then executes the vb script with [cscript](http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html) to emulate pressing the keyboard keys.

---

### Batch Script

**Note:** *Just save this to a text file with a `.bat` or `.cmd` extension and execute it to run.*

```
@ECHO OFF

explorer ms-settings:display
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > nul

:VBSDynamicBuild
SET TempVBSFile=%tmp%\~tmpSendKeysTemp.vbs
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}{UP 5}"                      >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "%%{F4}"                           >>"%TempVBSFile%"

CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"
EXIT
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Launch the Windows Settings app](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app)
- [SendKeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)
- [CScript](http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html)

Comment: @Justin - Let me know how it goes when you test this. The `{Tab}` and `{Up 5}` may need adjusted but from a larger scale to a smaller scale on my system it was just one tab and then a few up arrow presses but I put 5 because it can go up once at 100% more than that and it'll stay at 100% still from what I tested. The number [`#`] next to the `{TAB #}` or `{UP #}` indicates the number of times that key needs to be pressed on the GUI to go to each option so these may be different on your system but I tested as best I could here and that's what seems to work for me.

Comment: Perfect. I had to modify it a bit to send more {Tab}s but this definitely will do the trick.

Comment: I had to use 2 tabs in order to make this change the scale settings `ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB 2}{UP 6}"                      >>"%TempVBSFile%"`

Answer (score 13):

There's a command line app called [SetDPI](https://github.com/imniko/SetDPI)

Comment: I've tested this and can confirm that it works well. The pre-compiled release contains a single binary that allows you to set the DPI using e.g. `SetDPI.exe 150`

Comment: Thank you so much for this easy solution.  For me it was TAB 2 and DOWN 1 / UP 1 to switch between 100% and 125%. I created two bat files and added a shortcut for each witth a hotkey attributed.

Comment: This should be the best answer, thankyou