# Change Display Scaling on Main Monitor via Batch

Tags: multiple-monitors, batch, scaling

I followed this guide: [Is it possible to change display scaling via command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/1334781/is-it-possible-to-change-display-scaling-via-command-line) which works, but only for my secondary monitor which is set as monitor 1 and the main is monitor 2 in Windows.

I was wondering if there is a particular batch command that will let me switch it to my main monitor instead?

Any further help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try different {tab #} amounts?
on a single monitor I need different {tab #} amounts than on a multiple monitors system

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF

explorer ms-settings:display
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > nul

:VBSDynamicBuild
SET TempVBSFile=%tmp%\~tmpSendKeysTemp.vbs
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500 >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB 2}{DOWN 1}" >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500 >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "%%{F4}" >>"%TempVBSFile%"
CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"

explorer ms-settings:display
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > nul

:VBSDynamicBuild
SET TempVBSFile=%tmp%\~tmpSendKeysTemp.vbs
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500 >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB 18}{ENTER}{TAB 7}{DOWN}" >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500 >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "%%{F4}" >>"%TempVBSFile%"

CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"
EXIT
```

This will set both monitors to 125%