# Is it possible to change display scaling to 150% via command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, resolution, scaling

I found this batch file and it gets me close [Is it possible to change display scaling via command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/1334781/is-it-possible-to-change-display-scaling-via-command-line#_=)_ .   I'd like 1 batch file that gets me to 150% without any more clicking than a batch file called 150.bat and 1 batch file called 100.bat that gets me to 100% without any more input.   Is it possible?

I could call this 100.bat

```
@ECHO OFF

explorer ms-settings:display
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > nul

:VBSDynamicBuild
SET TempVBSFile=%tmp%\~tmpSendKeysTemp.vbs
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500 >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB 2}{UP 1}" >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500 >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "%%{F4}" >>"%TempVBSFile%"
CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"

explorer ms-settings:display
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > nul


CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"
EXIT
```

And this 125.bat

```
@ECHO OFF

explorer ms-settings:display
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > nul

:VBSDynamicBuild
SET TempVBSFile=%tmp%\~tmpSendKeysTemp.vbs
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500 >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB 2}{DOWN 1}" >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500 >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "%%{F4}" >>"%TempVBSFile%"
CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"

explorer ms-settings:display
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > nul


CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"
EXIT
```

However if they click one too many times they can go too far - I'd like it if I could set a specific number instead of moving up and down.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Before using `sendkeys`, bring the interface that you will "interact" to the foreground and then try to send inputs:

```all-bat
ECHO;WScript.Sleep 500 : objShell.AppActivate "Settings"
```

**2.** If you need to send TAB multiple times `"{TAB 2}{UP 1}"` , use:

```all-bat
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{UP}"
```

**3.** You need more one `%%` escaping in:

```all-bat
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "%%{F4}"

ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "%%%{F4}"
```

**4.** Whatever value (in `UPs/DOWn`) is already defined in the interface, you need to reset (bring it to the 1st position in the dropdown menu), and then set the item below in the listing ***x times*** necessary until you reach the desired listed value position:

```all-bat
echo;objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{~}{UP}{UP}{UP}{UP}"
echo;objShell.SendKeys "{UP}{UP}{UP}{DOWN}{~}"

:: it seems like a paranoid way of doing it, but it works...
```

---

---

- To change display scaling to **100**:

```all-bat
@echo off & setlocal

mode con: cols=50 Lines=02
2>nul del/q /f %tmp%\_tmp_send_keys_.vbs"
set "_tmp_send_keys_=%tmp%\_tmp_send_keys_.vbs"
explorer ms-settings:display && ping -n 2 127.1 >nul 

:vbs_dynamic_build_100
2>nul del/q /f "%_tmp_send_keys_%" & >"%_tmp_send_keys_%" ^
    (
     echo;Set objShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo;WScript.Sleep 500 : objShell.AppActivate "Settings"
     echo;objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{~}{UP}{UP}{UP}{UP}"
     echo;objShell.SendKeys "{UP}{UP}{UP}{~}%%%{F4}"
    ) && cscript //nologo "%_tmp_send_keys_%"

>nul 2>&1 (
explorer ms-settings:display & ping -n 4 -4 127.1 
%_APPDIRR__%taskkill/FI "WindowTitle eq Settings*"
del/q /f "%_tmp_send_keys_%" & endlocal & goto :EOF)
```

---

- To change display scaling to **125**:

```all-bat
@echo off & setlocal

mode con: cols=50 Lines=02
2>nul del/q /f %tmp%\_tmp_send_keys_.vbs"
set "_tmp_send_keys_=%tmp%\_tmp_send_keys_.vbs"
explorer ms-settings:display && ping -n 2 127.1 >nul 

:vbs_dynamic_build_125
2>nul del/q /f "%_tmp_send_keys_%" & >"%_tmp_send_keys_%" ^
    (
     echo;Set objShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo;WScript.Sleep 500 : objShell.AppActivate "Settings"
     echo;objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{~}{UP}{UP}{UP}{UP}"
     echo;objShell.SendKeys "{UP}{UP}{UP}{DOWN}{~}"
     echo;objShell.SendKeys "%%%{F4}"
    ) && cscript //nologo "%_tmp_send_keys_%"

>nul 2>&1 (
explorer ms-settings:display & ping -n 4 -4 127.1 
%_APPDIRR__%taskkill/FI "WindowTitle eq Settings*"
del/q /f "%_tmp_send_keys_%" & endlocal & goto :EOF)
```

---

- To change display scaling to **150**:

```all-bat
@echo off & setlocal

mode con: cols=50 Lines=02
2>nul del/q /f %tmp%\_tmp_send_keys_.vbs"
set "_tmp_send_keys_=%tmp%\_tmp_send_keys_.vbs"
explorer ms-settings:display && ping -n 2 127.1 >nul 

:vbs_dynamic_build_150
>"%_tmp_send_keys_%" (
     echo;Set objShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo;WScript.Sleep 500 : objShell.AppActivate "Settings"
     echo;objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{~}{UP}{UP}{UP}{UP}"
     echo;objShell.SendKeys "{UP}{UP}{UP}{DOWN}{DOWN}"
     echo;objShell.SendKeys "{~}%%%{F4}"
    ) && cscript //nologo "%_tmp_send_keys_%"

>nul 2>&1 (
explorer ms-settings:display & ping -n 4 -4 127.1 
%_APPDIRR__%taskkill/FI "WindowTitle eq Settings*"
del/q /f "%_tmp_send_keys_%" & endlocal & goto :EOF)
```

---

- Some further reading:

[√] **[SendKeys Method in VBScript](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)**

[√] **[***WshShell.SendKeys "Character_string_and/or_SendKeys"**](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)**